# react native yup email check

Tags: reactjs, react-native, yup

I want to check if the email is duplicate or not.

But my function to check the email is async.

Its looks like this:

```
email: yup.string()
  .required('Bitte trage deine Email aus.')
  .test('checkEmailAsync', 'Email already exists.', (value) => {

    checkEmail(value).then(res => {
      return res.result; // is true or false
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));

  })
```

It doesn't work. The function is being called every time prompting "email already exists.

My serverside response is correct I checked it.
I think it doesnt work because I use an async function in the test. But how can I check it now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try rewriting this way:

```
email: yup.string()
  .required('Bitte trage deine Email aus.')
  .test('checkEmailAsync', 'Email already exists.', async (value) => {
    const res = await checkEmail(value);
    return res.result;
    
  })
```